# Hibernate: Populate Some Fields From Web Service

Tags: spring, hibernate, web-services, spring-mvc

In our Spring MVC - Hibernate project we store uploaded files through a web service. However, we also keep information related to the file in a table in our database. A simplified version of the File class is as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FILE")
public class File {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    public int id;
    @Column(name="NAME")
    public String name;
    @Transient
    public byte[] data;

    public int getId() {
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
    }

    public String getName() {
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
    }
}
```

We load the File entity from our database and fetch its data from a web service as below:

```
File file = dao.getFileById({file_id});
byte[] data = webService.getFileData({file_id});
file.setData(data);
```

We use the File entity in a lot of places in our code, and every time we write a query to fetch a File we have to call the web service method to load its data. Also we have to do this for other entities that have a mapping to the File class like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PATIENT_FILE")
PatientFile {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FILE_ID")
    File file;

    ...
}
```

Now we have to manually fetch the binary data of the file from the web service whenever we load a PatientFile from the database.

Is there a way to have Hibernate do this automatically so that whenever a File entity is loaded, Hibernate fetches its data from the web service to populate the data field of the File object?

NOTE: I know I can implement the Lifecycle interface in the File class and override the onLoad method to do this, but I need a more centralized solution. Plus it wouldn't be nice to call a data layer method from the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can implement a [Hibernate Interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html). By implementing the `onLoad` method, which is called just before object initialization, you can make your web service call and populate the data. The method will have to check that it is a File object that you are loading.

Comment: Is the onLoad method called for only the root entity, or is it called for all entities whether they are loaded via a relationship mapping or an hql query?

Comment: It should be called on every object that gets initialized into Java regardless of whether it was loaded via relationship mapping or HQL, etc...